# Why can I not see the sign up form when I press on the Sign up link?

Tags: reactjs

My sign up form does not get displayed. Can you please help me to work out why?

I am new to React.  This is the code I have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route, 
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class SigninForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h2>I'm sign in form</h2>
        );
    }
}

class UserProfile extends Component {
    render() {
        const { user } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>User Profile</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SignupForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            state:{
            name,
            email,
            password,
            },
            onNameUpdate,
            onEmailUpdate,
            onPasswordUpdate,
            onSubmit,
            history,
        } = this.props;
        return (
        <div>
            <h2>I'm sign up form</h2>
            <div>
               <input type='text' onChange={e => onNameUpdate(e.target.value)} value={name} placeholder='Your name'/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='email' onChange={e => onEmailUpdate(e.target.value)} value={email} placeholder='Your email'/>  
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type='password' onChange={e => onPasswordUpdate(e.target.value)} value={password} placeholder='Your password'/>  
            </div>
            <div>
               <button type='button' onClick={ () => { 
                   onSubmit(); 
                   history.push('/app/user/profile')
                   }}>Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

const SignupFormWithRouter = withRouter(SignupForm);

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentUser: null,
            signUpForm: {
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
            }
        };
    }
    onNameUpdate(name) {
        const { signUpForm }= this.state;
        const updatedForm = Object.assign({}, signUpForm, {name});
        this.setState({
            signUpForm: updatedForm,
        });
    }
    onEmailUpdate(email) {
        const { signUpForm }= this.state;
        const updatedForm = Object.assign({}, signUpForm, {email});
        this.setState({
            signUpForm: updatedForm,
        });
    }
    onPasswordUpdate(password) {
        const { signUpForm }= this.state;
        const updatedForm = Object.assign({}, signUpForm, {password});
        this.setState({
            signUpForm: updatedForm,
        });
    }
    onSignUpSubmit(){
        const { signUpForm } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            currentUser:{
                name: signUpForm.name,
                email: signUpForm.email,
            },
            signUpForm: {
            name: ' ',
            email: ' ',
            password: ' ',
            },
        });
    }
    render() {
        const {currentUser, signUpForm}= this.state;
        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/app/signin">Sign In</Link></li>    
                    <li><Link to="/app/signup">Sign Up</Link></li>    
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/app/signup" render= { () => (
                        <SignupFormWithRouter
                        state={signUpForm}
                        onNameUpdate={this.onNameUpdate.bind(this)}
                        onEmailUpdate={this.onEmailUpdate.bind(this)}
                        onPasswordUpdate={this.onPasswordUpdate.bind(this)}
                        onSubmit={this.onSignUpSubmit.bind(this)}
                        />
                    )} />    
                    <Route path="/app/signin" component={ SignupForm } />
                    <Route path="/app/user/profile" render= { () => (
                        <UserProfile user={ currentUser }/>
                    )} />
                </div>
            </div> 
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
const container = document.getElementById("root");
render(
    <App />,
    container
);
```

Comment: In `SignupForm` shouldn't be `input` `value`s have `state.` prefix such as `value={state.name}`.

Comment: I have changed it but I still cannot see 'I am sign up form' when I press on Sign In hyperlink. I have placed the code on github: https://github.com/tomaszm-web/MyApp/tree/master